# What are possible reasons for memcached to be significantly slower on a remote server?

Tags: memcached, latency

I have a PHP/Apache server with 12GB of RAM. I have been running Memcached on the same machine with 6GB of allotted RAM.

I wanted to run Memcached on a separate server (same datacenter, vlan, subnet), just as I do for MySQL. I setup a separate, identical server with the same memcached configuration.

I am seeing a roughly 10x page load time using Memcached from the remote server than what I get when running locally. I have primed both caches and I still have a 10x load time from remote.

I'm having trouble trouble shooting this.

Comment: How do you think data is retrieved from the remote server?!?

Comment: To follow up on Macmade's comment: what is the *latency* difference? This should account for the difference: for the sake of comparison, a local connection has virtually no communication latency compared to Ethernet. Consider running some tests increasing (or decreasing) the number of memcached queries of a relatively small size to see how it fits into the page load time(s).

Comment: Guess someone should definitively invent RAM teleportation...

Comment: @Macmade There was a cute OPB show on yesterday about Quantum Mechanics ... totally done up for the general couch-surfer, but pretty interesting none-the-less. "All" that's needed to be done to teleport a human, apparently, is to generate a list of the state of *all* matter in the subject, generate a list (with more data than the number of stars in the known Universe) and ... crap. My mind can't make it past this step, never mind the the quantum entanglement stuff :)

Comment: Guess a simple malloc() won't make it allocating space for that data ; ) It's a pitty today's computers limit so much such ideas!

Comment: I have gigabit connectivity between all servers.

A ping shows 0.18ms average between servers. I have no latency issue with MySQL.

Comment: See my comment on the answer... : )

Answer (score 1):

You're loading 500kb of data per pageload, in all small keys? How many keys per pageload is this?

Latency to a remote server is very low, but running many roundtrips is still a bad idea. Memcached clients support multi-get operations, where you batch many keys into a single request/response with much lower latency.

Answer (score 0):

Just for info, DDR3-1333 is about 10667 MB/s.

If you have, let's say, Gigabit ethernet, I guess it can explains some of the problems you are experiencing...

Comment: I do have DDR3 and Gigabit between the servers.

Comment: So, to resume, 10GB/s (memory - local) versus 1GB/s (ethernet - remote)... Didn't you say it's 10 times slower with the remote server?

Comment: I'm not moving 10GB of data though. I'm retrieving a set of key->value pairs on each pageload, each of which are extremely small. In aggregate I'm moving less than 500kb of data between servers.

Comment: The amount of data doesn't matter. In local, the data is in RAM, and you have a direct access, so 10GB/s. With the remote server, the data is also in RAM, but not on the local machine. It still needs to be transferred to the local server, and that's done using ethernet, so 1GB/s... That's true for 1 byte, as fell as for 1 TeraByte of data.

Comment: To clarify, the page-load time went from < 1 second to 10 seconds. It's taking an extra 9 seconds to transfer over the network.

Shouldn't 500k at 1GB/s take about 0.0005 seconds to transfer?

Comment: Shouldn't 500k at 10GB/s transfer faster than 500k at 1GB/s ?

Comment: By the way, when communicating with a remote server, with Gigabit ethernet, you can't expect 1GB/s. You also need to consider the cost of establishing a connection, read data through sockets, etc. This also takes time...

Comment: How many key value pairs are you retrieving? You say there are 500Kb of data but they KV pairs are small - sounds like there's a large number of items being retrieved.